# Visual Studio 2012 shows xaml errors which are no errors

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012

I do for example for a window:

```
Icon="/Prayon.Common.Images;component/Application/Prayon.ico"
```

This is working great and there are no Errors in Visual Studio 2010. Now, in Visual Studio 2012 I see the error

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Prayon.Common.Images;component\Application\Prayon.ico'.
```

in the errorlist. But the `Prayon.ico` is in the Assembly `Prayon.Common.Images` which is correct referenced.

Why is Visual Studio 2012 reporting this as an error?

I can compile and run the Project without problems. There are only a lot of error-messages in the ErrorList of VS2012 and this makes it hard to get "real" errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im pretty sure you are referencing the image in a funny way , 
shouldnt be more like this ?

```
pack://application:,,,/Resources/Prayon.png"
```

or more precisely this

```
<Image Source="/ClassLibraryName;Component/images/myimage.png"/>
```

You can find out more about WPF pack URIs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx